# Excel Conditional Formatting - Containing Multiple Matches

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Trying to avoid VBA and use one Conditional Formatting rule.

I want to apply a format to cells that contain one or more possible phrases.

```
   |   A    |
---+--------+---
 1 | foo    |
 2 | bar    |
 3 | foobar |
 4 | baz    |
 5 | foobaz |
 6 | qux    |
 7 | barqux |
```

Goal: apply conditional format to 'foo' and 'baz' (rows 1,3,4,5)

Something like the following should work, however I think the problem is in identifying the current cell to compare, in this case the `A1:A7` needs to be the current cell reference:

```
=OR( IFERROR(FIND("foo",A1:A7),0) > 0, IFERROR(FIND("baz",A1:A7),0) > 0 )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

Even though the conditional format was being applied to the range $A$1:$A$7, all you need to do is refer to the first cell in the function.

```
=OR( IFERROR(FIND("foo",A1),0) > 0, IFERROR(FIND("baz",A1),0) > 0 )
```

It'll automatically increment so long as you don't use the lock operator (`$`).  - Sorry if this is common knowledge.  I'm going to keep this here for educational purpose, if no one has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're perfectly right. You have to enter the reference to the "selected" cell. E.g. if you click into cell A1 and then drag and select cells A1..A7 you will see that A1 has different background than the other cells. This is your current cell for the conditional formula. I.e.

```
=OR( IFERROR(FIND("foo",A1),0) > 0, IFERROR(FIND("baz",A1),0) > 0 )
```

would be correct in this case. For the other cells the formula will then be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I've been doing so much database work lately, I don't know if this is common knowledge or not.  What do you think?  I would just make a VBA macro, but I plan on sharing it with people that might have the security enabled.  I assume it's common knowledge if you work with C-Formatting a lot, but none of the examples I saw in the help describe this and I couldn't find it on SO or Experts Exchange.

Comment: Actually I do not know why I know this. Nevertheless it often helped me out and you can solve various issues with relative or absolute references in conditional formatting. The reference cell is not necessarily within your selected range. E.g. with the formula =$A1="XYZ" you can format a complete line depending on the content of a single column or with =A1=MAX($A$1:$A$7) you can mark the maximum value within a list.